# find intersection of line and a plane

Tags: math, graphics, line, plane

How can I find the intersection of the following line and plane using only their following parametric representation?:

- line: (3,2,0) + (-1,1,5)t
- plane: (0,-1,4) + (1,1,0)t + (5,1,-2)s

Comment: Intersection occurs where the line and plane have the same x, y and z values.  So set the line equation equal to the plane equation and solve for the resulting point.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.  It more properly belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com.